# Hyphenating problem when using ebgaramond

Tags: hyphenation

Currently I am facing a problem of hyphenation when i used the package `\usepackage{ebgaramond}`, but when i remove this package (i.e `\usepackage{ebgaramond}`) hyphenation goes fine, but i need the text font style which is creating in `\usepackage{ebgaramond}`  here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[twoside,letterpaper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}


\usepackage{parallel,graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\rightmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thepage} %% To display numbering on every page alternately left and right

\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\jChapter}[1]{\noindent\scalebox{2.5}{\color{red}\textbf{#1}\hspace{0.3mm}}}
\newcommand{\jverse}[1]{\noindent\textcolor{cyan}{\scalebox{1.0}{\textbf{#1\hspace{1.0mm}}}}}
\newcommand{\story}[1]{\vspace*{2mm}\centering\it\textbf{#1}}


\newcommand\versenumcolor{red}
\newcommand\chapnumcolor{red}


\title{Karbi}
\date{}
\author{}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\emph{\alph{footnote}}}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter


\part*{The Old Testament}
  \setlength{\columnseprule}{.5pt}
\twocolumn
\begin{Parallel}{9.1cm}{9.1cm}
{\jChapter{10}While the Israelites were camped in Gilgal they kept passover the in the evening on the fourteenth day of the month in the plains of Jericho. }
{\jverse{11}On the day after the passover, on that very day, they ate the produce of the land, unleavened cakes and parched grain. }
{\jverse{12}The manna ceased on the day they ate the produce of the land, and the Israelites no longer had manna; they ate the crops of the land of Canaan that year. }
\end{Parallel}

\end{document}
```

below is the image when i used `\usepackage{ebgaramond}`
[image]

When i donot use the package `\usepackage{ebgaramond}` here is the output 
[image]

Comment: This is a just a case of bad luck and a word that won't hyphenate according to the usual rules.  You can manage this either by adding `\hyphenation{pass-over}` in the preamble, or by adding a discretionary hyphen in the word itself: `pass\-over`.  I maintain the hyphenation exception list, and will add this word.

Comment: This can be possible only if there is a few text but i have thounsands of thousand text, so it will difficult for me type like this `\hyphenation{pass-over}` @barbarabeeton

Comment: It looks like `ebgaramond` sets tighter than, for example, computer modern.  However, this can potentially happen with any font.  Since it seems you are using the default U.S. hyphenation patterns, you might take a look at [`ushyphex`](http://mirror.ctan.org/documentation/digests/tugboat/hyphenex)

Comment: @BikiTeron You need `\hyphenation{pass-over}` just once in the document preamble.

Comment: Will it work for another word also because my text is just a problem of type, the word may not be passover, iwant generalize to split the word automatically. @egreg

Comment: @BikiTeron See my answer. TeX does its best, but some words can slip through the hyphenation algorithm. Add the ones you find necessary.

Comment: Two additional suggestions: (1) you have narrow columns so allow some raggedness on the right, load the `ragged2e` package and adjust the parameters; (2) use the `microtype` package for some more flexibility in spacing.

Answer (score 3):

Somehow, “passover” slips through the hyphenation patterns for American English.

You can declare a hyphenation exception, by adding `\hyphenation{pass-over}` in the preamble.

```latex
\documentclass[twoside,letterpaper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}


\usepackage{parallel,graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\rightmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thepage} %% To display numbering on every page alternately left and right

\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\jChapter}[1]{\noindent\scalebox{2.5}{\color{red}\textbf{#1}\hspace{0.3mm}}}
\newcommand{\jverse}[1]{\noindent\textcolor{cyan}{\scalebox{1.0}{\textbf{#1\hspace{1.0mm}}}}}
\newcommand{\story}[1]{\vspace*{2mm}\centering\itshape\bfseries#1}


\newcommand\versenumcolor{red}
\newcommand\chapnumcolor{red}

% hyphenation exceptions
\hyphenation{
  pass-over
  % other words you need (the following are just by way of example)
  anti-deriv-a-tives
  anti-holo-mor-phic
 }


\title{Karbi}
\date{}
\author{}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\emph{\alph{footnote}}}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter


\part*{The Old Testament}
  \setlength{\columnseprule}{.5pt}
\twocolumn
\begin{Parallel}{9.1cm}{9.1cm}
{\jChapter{10}While the Israelites were camped in Gilgal they kept passover the in the evening on the fourteenth day of the month in the plains of Jericho. }
{\jverse{11}On the day after the passover, on that very day, they ate the produce of the land, unleavened cakes and parched grain. }
{\jverse{12}The manna ceased on the day they ate the produce of the land, and the Israelites no longer had manna; they ate the crops of the land of Canaan that year. }
\end{Parallel}

\end{document}
```

Note that you just type `passover` in the text. Add other problematic words, should the need arise. You can also add

```
\input{ushyphex}
```

just before `\hyphenation`, so to load all the known exceptions.

I changed `\it` into `\itshape` (the command `\it` has been deprecated for more than 20 years).

[image]

Comment: It is just like a manually kind of things, I have a thousands of thousands text this will be very difficult to write down all the problematics words, is there any other solution? @egreg

Comment: @BikiTeron Why moaning before trying? Chances are good that just a few exceptions will be needed.

Comment: I  have checked , it shows problem for other words also. what will be reason for not hyphenating automaticaly by LaTeX. @egreg

Comment: @BikiTeron And the number of words is? Sorry, but this is going nowhere. TeX knows rules to hyphenate correctly the more common English words. It hasn't gobbled a dictionary of hyphenation points, but uses an algorithm that is very efficient at the expense, for languages like English, of not being able to find *all* correct hyphenation points.

Comment: But the text which i have is an English language only,so please let me know where i am doing mistake. @egreg

Comment: @BikiTeron ***You are doing no mistake***. TeX ***does not*** guarantee to find ***all*** correct hyphenation points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94906/discussion-between-biki-teron-and-egreg).